# How do I display json data in select box?

Tags: javascript, html, json

```
{"BD": "Bangladesh", "BE": "Belgium", "BF": "Burkina Faso", "BG": "Bulgaria"}
```

How could I display this data as options in select box in html using javascript?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is very simple if you use with Javascript. Do this,

```js
var countries = {"BD": "Bangladesh", "BE": "Belgium", "BF": "Burkina Faso", "BG": "Bulgaria"};
var selectHTML='';

for (var key in countries)
 {
     selectHTML +='<option value="'+key+'">'+countries[key]+'</option>';
 }
 
 document.getElementById('countries').innerHTML = selectHTML;
```

```html
<div id="select_box_wrapper">
  <select id="countries"></select>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Iterate over your array with let country of countries and add your info as text and value to your select drop-down. Text would be the abbreviation such as BE and value would be Belgium.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a way of solving the problem without jQuery, and without appending the HTML strings. I am using the [`Option`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/HTMLOptionElement) constructor to create an option in the drop-down menu and inserting that into the `select` element.

```js
var data = {"BD": "Bangladesh", "BE": "Belgium", "BF": "Burkina Faso", "BG": "Bulgaria"};

var selectControl = document.getElementById("countries");

for(var prop in data) {
  if(data.hasOwnProperty(prop)) {
    var option = new Option();
    option.text = data[prop];
    option.value = prop;
    selectControl.options[selectControl.options.length] = option;
  }
}
```

```html
<select id="countries">
</select>
```